# Random blocks without for loop

Tags: matlab

In the code below I want to generate 7 random start points. I then want to take these start points and select the column number in matrix Delta that corresponds to the first randomly chosen start point.  I then also include the next 47 columns after that column. Then I should use the next of the random start points, select the corresponding column from Delta and again include the following 47 columns. And so on until all random start points have been used.

The problem is that when I use the code below it only works for the first random start point and ignores the rest?

Can this be done without having to loop?

```
LogData=log(data);

Delta=diff(LogData,1,2);

max_t=size(Delta,2);

Start_YC=LogData(:,max_t);

Urnd=randi(max_t,7,1);

SRtns=Delta(:,Urnd:Urnd+47);
```

Comment: Is it okay to have overlapping columns between the loop iterations?

Comment: Yes (probably not ideal but the algorithm doesn't forbid it)

Comment: BTW where is your loop? You said you want to do-away with loop, which isn't visible.

Comment: I am trying to do it without the loop, if you replace the last line with SRtns=Delta(:,Urnd); then it works but only gives you the 7 starting columns. I had hoped to get the full version working without having to loop

Comment: 7 or whatever the size of the second parameter of randi(max_t,7,1) happens to be

Comment: Well I basically meant how many columns do you expect in `SRtns`? In the loop version it is `7`, so in the without-loop version, shouldn't it be `7 x 48` = `336`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works out for you -

```
rand_start_pts = randperm(max_t-47,7)
ind = bsxfun(@plus,rand_start_pts(:),0:47)'
SRtns = Delta(:,ind(:))
```